# I'm getting error: SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

I have my own server (where I'm running `Apache/2.4.26`), and today I realized that from (Brave and Google Chrome - different computers) I'm getting from my websites this error;

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

mywebsite.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

And the strange thing is that I'm getting this error every fifth click on my website.

From my conf file:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite/chain.pem
SSLCompression off
```

from `options-ssl-apache.conf`;

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
```

I have checked log file from website but nothing, also nothing here; `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

I'm trying to figure out what is causing this error, any ideas where can I find more info or even better, how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

If I try `openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.com:443`, it will return:

I'm using: `OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)

...

3073276480:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:469:
```

Also If I change SSLProtocol to `SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2`, it will return me the same error.

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

As someone suggested I changed options-ssl-apache.conf into:

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite           HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SSLv3:!SSLv2:!TLSv1
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

#SSLSessionTickets       off
```

I also tried to add `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` into my virtualhost conf file, and in a same time I did change couple of things here; `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf`

```
#SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SSLv3:!SSLv2:!TLSv1

SSLHonorCipherOrder on

#   The protocols to enable.
#   Available values: all, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
#   SSL v2  is no longer supported
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

**EDIT:**

After changing LogLevel into Info it returns:

```
[Sat Jul 08 13:34:53.374307 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 8710] [client] AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server mywebsite:443)
[Sat Jul 08 13:34:53.374717 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 8710] SSL Library Error: error:140940F4:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:unexpected message
[Sat Jul 08 13:34:53.374750 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 8710] [client] AH01998: Connection closed to child 1 with abortive shutdown (server mywebsite:443)
```

Still searching for soultion...

Comment: You are using Let's Encrypt for the website certificate correct and are NOT using OpenSSL to self-sign a certificate?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I do.

Comment: Update your question.  Your Apache configuration file doesn't match if your now only using TLSv1.2 protocol. Your error still indicates a SSLv3 error which isn't good.

Comment: TLS is still largely based on SSL3. It’s not that strange it would go through some of the same functions, which is why it says SSL3. As such, the error message is perfectly normal. Either end of the connection may be buggy or subject to interference (like buggy firewalls).

Comment: By the way, instead of following bogus advice from around the net, use the [Mozilla SSL Config Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) to generate a secure configuration. If after this it still isn’t working, the fact remains that it’s simply a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to downgrade Apache to 2.4.7 and not it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

So, there's a few things here, and now you're going to dig yourself into a deep hole by trying to roll only the most modern security ciphers and protocols.

Firstly, your SSL ciphers.  By doing `!SSL3` and `!TLS1` you are disabling *every* supported TLS cipher; in addition, by only selecting the four ciphers you specified, you also prohibit other TLS1.2-compatible ciphers which may be more 'compatible' over TLS1.2 with LE and other services. 
 (And they'll still return the error code you're seeing if you can't negotiate, it's a standard error message not *necessarily* an indicator of SSLv2 or SSLv3 being attempted.)

Secondly, your SSL Protocols.  While it's *great* to disable SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1, and TLSv1.1, a lot of stuff isn't 'updated' to support only TLSv2 ciphers that you've selected.  Therefore, you should offer a more "legacy" set of protocols and ciphers so everything properly communicates.  Especially if you're using 14.04 on a server or endpoint system (based on your now-deleted post at Ask Ubuntu), because of the age of OpenSSL on that system.  (And no, your issue isn't `SSLv3` related).

I quite like [Mozilla's SSL config generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/), for doing this, but I also quite like using [Cipherli.st's configurations](https://cipherli.st/).  The second here offers a 'legacy' set of SSL configurations like this (NOTE: This list is not up to date, I recommend you refer to either Mozilla's SSL Config generator or Cipherli.st for updated 'legacy' options, though TLS1.1 and lower are considered "old" by Mozilla now):

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4 
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
# Requires Apache >= 2.4 
SSLCompression off
SSLSessionTickets Off 
SSLUseStapling on 
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
```

Note that I tend to use these legacy things for some of my older android devices, so they can view my web services (NGINX-served, not Apache, but same difference).

If you *really* want to roll ultra-hardened security like you're trying to do (TLSv1.2 only and very VERY strong ciphers), you should consider that a good portion of the Internet and many IoT devices won't be able to reach your site or services.  LetsEncrypt may be included in this list.  This is why it's "okay" to use Intermediate (Mozilla) or Legacy (Cipherli.st) ciphersets and protocl settings.  It may not get you the ultra high 100%-across-the-board SSL score on SSLLabs, but it *will* get you A+ on sites you choose to use.

---

One other consideration point is I think you're missing some critical parts for your DH-based ciphers you've selected.  You need a DH parameters file to be defined.  The evils of Apache make this a little bit harder to enable.  You'll basically need to generate a DH parameters file of 2048 bits or stronger, and then add that to the end of your SSL certificate. 
 `openssl dhparam 2048 >> /path/to/site/certificate` should do this, though you may want to make a copy of your certificate in user-writable space to make sure you properly edit the file.  (Then move that file back to the directory with another name to indicate it has the DHParam and then use that).

Comment: I should point out that with LE I can't get it to work for my sites running the most secure configs either - I usually have to use the TLSv1 and up settings to make that work.  (Though, I usually don't use LE certs.)

Comment: @user134969 by "shared hosting" you mean you have multiple sites on one system or you are using shared hosting from some company?